# Ajax form not showing up with ruby on rails form_remote_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is all new territory for me, but I am working through a Rails book that was written before start_form_tag was deprecated and I am running into problems with the books example code using remote_form_tag. I have the other forms working but can't get this one up and running. Here's the code:

```
<h1>Categories</h1>

<ul id="category_list">
    <%= render :partial => 'category', :collection => @categories %>
</ul>

<br/>

 <p id="add_link"><%= link_to_function("Add a category", "Element.remove('add_link');       
         Element.show('add_category')") %></p>

 <div id="add_category" style="display:none;">
     <%= form_remote_tag(:url => {:action => 'new'}, 
                     :update => "category_list", 
             :position => :bottom, 
                 :html => {:id => 'category_form'}) %>
       Name: <%= text_field "category", "name" %>
       <%= submit_tag 'Add' %>
    <%= end_form_tag %>
 </div>
```

This is exactly how it appears in the book, and doesn't compile. I've tried changing to match the form_tag blocks but the form enclosed by the "add_category" div never shows up.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Just found that it doesn't appear that the prototype script is not getting loaded.
both the remove and show methods on Element are showing up as undefined in Firebug. I am not sure why it is not showing up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left out the = sign when including the javascript libraries in standard.html

Line should be this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Vote to close this question?

Comment: D'oh! Easy mistake to make.  Yeah, wait a couple days and accept it so future searchers will have something to refer to.